# how to make dropdown menu select the option you clicked on last time

Tags: html, css

as I said in the title I am trying to make my dropdown menu select the last option i clicked on for example:https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid
in some youtube channels if you select videos and click on SORT BY then choose any option then if you click on sort by again you will see the last option you clicked is selected

(css is internal) this is my code:

html:

```
 <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 89%">   <div tabindex="0" class="menu">
<div class="menu-dropdown">
    <a href="mostpopular.html">Most Popular</a>
    <a href="newest.html">Newest</a>
    <a href="oldest.html">Oldest</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
/* style for the css menu dropdown container */
.menu {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
z-index:2; padding:0;
margin:0;
outline:0;
text-align:left;
}

/* style for the button */
.menu:before {
content: "\2630 \a0 Menu"; 
color:white;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid #555;
border-radius:3px;
background: #96305e;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #96305e 0%, #822956 10%, #822956 90%, #751749 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #96305e 0%,#822956 10%,#822956 90%,#751749 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #96305e 0%,#822956 10%,#822956 90%,#751749 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#96305e', 
endColorstr='#751749',GradientType=0 );
}

.menu:focus { pointer-events:none; }

/* If :focus detected the dropdown menu is displayed by making it visible */
.menu:focus .menu-dropdown { opacity:1; visibility:visible; }

/* style for the dropdown box */
.menu-dropdown {
background-color: #364656;
width: auto;
margin:3px 0 0 0;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px black solid;
border-radius:3px;
pointer-events: auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: visibility 1s;
background: #1f8bd3;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1f8bd3 0%, #1b7aba 10%, #1b7aba 90%, #1b61b7 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1f8bd3 0%,#1b7aba 10%,#1b7aba 90%,#1b61b7 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1f8bd3 0%,#1b7aba 10%,#1b7aba 90%,#1b61b7 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1f8bd3', 
endColorstr='#1b61b7',GradientType=0 );
}

/* style the links in the dropdown */
.menu-dropdown a {
background:transparent;
border:none;
outline:0;
display:block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
width:160px;
padding:5px;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Full Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <div id="header">
 <div class="container">
 <a href="main lol.html">Home</a>
 <ul id="header-nav">
 <li><a href="about.html" >About</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="downloads.html">Download Links</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <body>
 <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 89%">   
 <div tabindex="0" class="menu">
 <div class="menu-dropdown">
 <a href="mostpopular.html" target="_blank">Most Popular</a>
 <a href="newest.html" target="_blank">Newest</a>
 <a href="oldest.html" target="_blank">Oldest</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <style>
 /* style for the css menu dropdown container */
.menu {
       position:relative;
       display:inline-block;
       z-index:2; padding:0;
       margin:0;
       outline:0;
       text-align:left;
    }

/* style for the button */
.menu:before {
content: "\2630 \a0 Menu"; 
color:white;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid #555;
border-radius:3px;
background: #96305e;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #96305e 0%, #822956 10%, #822956 
90%, #751749 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #96305e 0%,#822956 10%,#822956 
90%,#751749 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #96305e 0%,#822956 10%,#822956 
90%,#751749 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
startColorstr='#96305e', endColorstr='#751749',GradientType=0 );
}

.menu:focus { pointer-events:none; }

/* If :focus detected the dropdown menu is displayed by making it visible 
 */
.menu:focus .menu-dropdown { opacity:1; visibility:visible; }

/* style for the dropdown box */
.menu-dropdown {
background-color: #364656;
width: auto;
margin:3px 0 0 0;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px black solid;
border-radius:3px;
pointer-events: auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: visibility 1s;
background: #1f8bd3;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1f8bd3 0%, #1b7aba 10%, #1b7aba 
 90%, #1b61b7 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1f8bd3 0%,#1b7aba 10%,#1b7aba 
90%,#1b61b7 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1f8bd3 0%,#1b7aba 10%,#1b7aba 
90%,#1b61b7 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
startColorstr='#1f8bd3', endColorstr='#1b61b7',GradientType=0 );
}

 /* style the links in the dropdown */
.menu-dropdown a {
background:transparent;
border:none;
outline:0;
display:block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
width:160px;
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</body>
<center>
<h1>Games</h1>
<h3>
<a href="https://direct-link.net/165397/script"target="_blank" >Roblox 
autorob script</a><br>
<a href=""target="_blank">8 ball pool hack no root</a><br>
</h3>
</center>
<div id="footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="column">
<h4>My Links</h4>
<p>
<a href="https://web.facebook.com/YousefRaedXD" 
 target="_blank">Facebook</a><br>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6x7kvBibYzem6i59UMc3kw" 
 target="_blank">Youtube</a>
 </p>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
 <h4>My Story</h4>
 <p>Hi there! I study in middle school and i wish to be a web programmer 
 :3</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Full css (external):

```
#header-nav li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 20px;
}
#header-nav {
display: block;
float:right;
margin-top:0;
}
#header {
background-color: #1abc9c;
height: 150px;
line-height: 150px;
}
container {
max-width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
}
#header-title {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#header a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;

text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
#header a:hover {
color: #222;
}
#footer {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
padding: 50px 0;
}
.column {
min-width: 300px
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
#footer h4 {
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.1em
}
#footer p {
color:white;
}
a {
color: #1abc9c;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #F6A623;
}
.post {
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 60px 0;
}
.post-author img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.post-author span {
margin-left: 16px;
}
.post-date {
color: D2D2D2;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color: #333;
}
p {
line-height: 1.5;
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
body {
margin: 0;
color: #555;

font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.post, .about {
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 60px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a form in your menu and send by post or get (No matter which one) the last one you picked so, you'll be able to display it with a little bit of php.

```
<?php
   echo"<button>{$_GET['lastOne']}</button>";
?>
```

!!! Only If I correctly understood the question !!!
What I understood is you want to add, like a history in your dropdown menu and the last button would be a link to the last one you visited

***EDIT***

Here is the code I told you I would make for you, prob not the best way to do it, but it's working

```
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 89%">
  <div tabindex="0" class="menu">
    <div class="menu-dropdown">
      <a href="mostpopular.php?lastButtonClicked=mostpopular">Most Popular</a>
      <a href="newest.php?lastButtonClicked=newest">Newest</a>
      <a href="oldest.php?lastButtonClicked=oldest">Oldest</a>
      <?php
        if (isset($_GET['lastButtonClicked']))
        {
          $lastButtonClicked = $_GET['lastButtonClicked'];
          echo"<a href='$lastButtonClicked'>Last button clicked</a>";
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you understood me right but can i add this code anywhere in my index.html file?

Comment: Well, not in your html file ,you'll need to change to be a php file. If you are testing your page on your computer simply by double clicking it, php don't work like this. You'll need to setup an Web Server on your computer. I personnaly use AMPPS. I will edit my post with the code you'll need

Comment: So first of all i should make a new php file and copy paste my code there then i run ampps after that i copy paste the code you wrote in EDIT right?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget the part of the code with <html> <heder></header><body>....... And this part of the code will need to be in every page to be useful

Comment: i have done everything but when i open the .php file in internet explorer it tells me save or open i pressed open like 3 times then pressed save and open but nothing happens like it runs explorer then closes directly that i can't even spot what is in there, please help me or send me an instruction video if possible , Thank you

Comment: Here is the video how to install Ampps : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9au54FTwPQM   But I don't really understand what is the problem, because when I use it, I simply put my php file in C:\Program File\Ampps\www\ and then I open Ampps and test my web page. You can also use mamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwQW0Qy85jY

Comment: I did the same thing but the css doesn't get activated like there is no css in the page

Comment: You forgot to add your html, head and body tag. I didn't tought I had to create it completely for you. I simply modified the code you gave me. You need to put the code I gave you inside the body tag https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp and to link your css https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: You dont need MySQL for your site, MySQL is à database driver. I'm not a professionnal of Ampps installation, but what I do is install Ampps, launch it and in the app in the right bottom corner of your screen and I click on the folder Icon and I create a new folder and I open chrome and type localhost/FOLDER_NAME as url.

Comment: I installed mamp , css is working and the file is .php but the last button i clicked on isn't marked or selected when i click menu it is in the <body> tag tho

Comment: I cant help without the entire code sorry

Comment: do i edit the question and put the entire code?

Comment: Yes you can, but dont replace the existing one, add a section and write edit

Comment: done! btw some of the css is internal and some is external

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to reply, really busy these days. I'll try to take a look at it